# Programatically render template area in Magnolia CMS

Tags: rendering, render, andengine, magnolia

I search for rendering specific content in Magnolia like components with Render Engine So I found this topic on stackoverflow : [Programatically render template area in Magnolia CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346351/programatically-render-template-area-in-magnolia-cms/34334127#34334127)

My question is about the structure of the following classes : FilteringAppendableWrapper and
FakeResponse : used to put fake Http Response in the AppendableFilteringResponseOutputProvider

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What about it do yo want to ask? Why he didn't use the real response? Because he was faking whole (web) request to a page too and then getting output from his "FakeResponse" and adding it to json array to fill in body of the response of a request that came over REST.
Personally, I think such solution is overkill for the job and if I had to do the same, I would probably simply register variation template for a component or whole page and when requesting page w/ e.g. .ajax extension I would have my variation to kick in and rendered whole page (or area or component) as a json array.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Can you please explain what is variation template and if it's possible to give me an example. I am new in Magnolia and Thank you.

Comment: Hey Jan did you mean something like this !

    Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession("website");
       
    Node content = session.getNode("/protoTest/content/02");
       
    componentDefinition = templateDefinitionAssignment.getAssignedTemplateDefinition(content);
       
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
       
    renderingEngine.render(content, componentDefinition, new HashMap<String, Object>(), new AppendableOnlyOutputProvider(writer));

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. Magnolia allows you to have defined multiple template definitions for same content and then based on e.g. extension with which you request the resource, you can control in which format that resource will be rendered. See https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Configuring+variations+in+a+page+template for more details.

Comment: Thanks Jan I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for fake response. This simple code work well :

```
        Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession("website");

        Node content = session.getNode("/protoTest/content/01");

        componentDefinition = templateDefinitionAssignment.getAssignedTemplateDefinition(content);

        OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);

        appendable = new AppendableOnlyOutputProvider(writer);

        renderingEngine.render(content, componentDefinition, new HashMap<String, Object>(), appendable);

        ((Writer) appendable.getAppendable()).flush();

        System.out.println(outputStream.toString());
```